# Convert a stream of Promises into a stream of values

Tags: promise, rxjs

I am somewhat new to RxJs and I am trying to mix the world of promises and observables.

Here is what I want:
I have an observable (call it `clickObs`) which listens to a click and as a result interrogates a database, producing a promise which resolves to a value when the database querying concludes (successfully). 
My observable thus generates a stream of promises from a stream of clicks, and what I want is to generate from that observable, a stream of corresponding resolved values.

From past questions on stackoverflow, I read about `defer`, `flatMap`, `mergeAll`, and `fromPromise`, but cannot get my head around how to articulate the four to solve my problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need all four, just look at [`flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) or its sibling [`flatMapLatest`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmaplatest.md)

```
clickObs.flatMapLatest(function() {
  //Access the db and return a promis
  return database.query(queryObj);
})
.subscribe(function(result) {
  //Result is implicitly flattened out
  /*Do something with the result*/
});
```

`flatMap` will implicitly convert a promise or array-like object into an `Observable` and flatten out the resulting sequence. `FlatMapLatest` is similar but will ignore old events, if a newer one arrives before the previous one completed.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you. I agree that in my use case ´flatMapLatest´ is the way to go.

Comment: For those who like further reading, just stumbled on that article, which explains wonderfully this exact case : https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: Note that just ignoring old events rather than cancelling them is often inappropriate, it's often better to explicitly specify how dispose works rather than just return a promise if that applies.